# Offline Android admob ads

Tags: android, admob, ads, offline

I have integrated Admob ads using Google Play Services in my application. Now I want to implement offline ads. Is there a way to show ads when device is offline?
Is it possible to cache the ads and save the redirecting url of the ads shown by admob and use these details when device is offline?

Thanks,

Harshit

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE AT ALL... bcoz if you show offline ads ...you wont be generating any revenue..so

Comment: Thanks for your comment but what if we can have access to the ad link and save the no of clicks while device is offline and when the device gets connected, hit that ad link in background.

Comment: as for as my knowledge goes this is not possible, secondly admob doesn't accept post request....so

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with AdMob. But there are a few services that allows you to create HTML5 ads that you can store offline, like [Celtra](http://www.celtra.com) or [GearAds](http://www.gearads.net)

Answer (score 0):

If user have success first initiation adMob, it will show same ads on same widget Ads, different page. event when user offline. from my experience.